# What is the point of the [website] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is not a burninate request... yet. Before I create one of those I want to get a better understanding of why this tag exists.

Here is the description of the [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/website) tag:

> DO NOT USE. Select some more descriptive tags, like html, css, php, http, etc.

So if we aren't supposed to use the tag what purpose does it serve? If its existence is simply to tell people not to use it, it seems a bit pointless. Thoughts?